Issue with Depicter in WordPress: Sections Not Displaying Properly
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I'm experiencing an issue with Depicter in WordPress. I've configured Depicter to display sections on my WordPress site, but I'm having trouble with the display of CSS styles. Currently, only text elements are displaying correctly, while styles, colors, and buttons are not rendering.
I've checked my CSS files to ensure they are properly loaded and that there are no errors in the browser console. Additionally, I've disabled all other plugins to check for conflicts, but the issue persists.
Does anyone have any insight into what might be causing this problem or how I could troubleshoot it? I'm open to any suggestions or advice.
Thank you in advance for your help!
